# updating a referenced field in mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to "clear" my referenced field in my mongo db. 
I am using mongoose, so i have a modelSchema like this.

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({

    userName: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean },
    email: { type: String },
    profile: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'profiles'
    }
})
```

So my question is... if i already have an objectId added in my profile field...
how can i clear that field?

I am receiving from my client an update request with a json like this.

```
{ userName: 'admin',
  password: '123',
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  profile: '',
  isAdmin: true }
```

and my controller do this.

```
usersCtrl.updateUser = (req, res) => {

    userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }).then(() => {
        res.json('updated')
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.json(err)
    })
}
```

but i get this error

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "profile"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem, adding this code in my controller

```
usersCtrl.updateUser = (req, res) => {

if(req.body.profile == ''){
req.body.profile = null
}
    userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }).then(() => {
        res.json('updated')
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.json(err)
    })
}
```